# Cordova CLI command returns nothing even "cordova --version", installation issue?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, npm

Recently, I needed to try developing a cordova application. I installed android studio with no problem. Then I went on for Nodejs. I got **Nodejs 6.0** installed on my **Windows 7** system.

It worked fine. Then I tried to install cordova 
with npm command :

```
npm install -g cordova
```

It seemed finally ok. The verbose message appeared and the graphical text displayed the folder structure of the installed components, which I thought, this tells me the success install.

When I typed `node --version`, it showed  `6.0.0`, the nodejs has been installed correctly.

Then I typed `npm --version`, it showed `3.8.8`. So `npm` works ok.

After that, I typed `cordova --version` to validate the installation, it seemed to fetch something for a little while and return the prompt without printing anything or even its version.

I took another try,  I typed `cordova help`. Same thing, there's nothing happen. It just failed or got error somehow silently.

I removed cordova with `npm uninstall -g cordova`, and tried install again to eventually get the same result.  I even tried to remove nodejs and re-install all over again but no luck.

Is there anyone out there faced the same to me? And how did you solve this problem? Any idea?

Comment: Is this in Windows? What is the version of your OS?

Comment: @user1040224 could u try 'npm install -g cordova@6.1.1'

Comment: @Gandhi, I did try as you suggested but still no luck.  Also, before reinstall I had uninstall the cordova. And at the end of the verbose message on uninstall it showed "cordova-6.1.1", which means the version I installed before was already 6.1.1.  But I tried put '@6.1.1' on reinstalling again anyway, and the problem still not solve.

Comment: Is there anything to do with Android Studio? Conflict or something?

Comment: @user1040224 could you try installing Cordova in verbose mode and post de complete installation trace? Also are you able to add and build platform after install?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure this is in your System Path (under : `PC -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables`)

   > C:\Users\ `Your User` \AppData\Roaming\npm
2. Try to close and re-open your command prompt ;)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I already got the path as you mentioned. But the problem is still there :' (

Comment: Are you using Taco tools with Visual Studio or anything like that?

Comment: No, Phobis, I don't have them in my machine.